# Using FastICA to split a signal bands based on frequency

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to split the bands of a signal and I used butterworth filter and It worked fine but I need to know how can I split the bands of the signal using [FastICA](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/) package. Any help?? Lets say I need to split it into 3 bands (band one : 1 - 5 Hz,band one : 6 - 10 Hz and band one : 11 - 15 Hz).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, FastICA only implements Independent Component Analysis a.k.a. Blind Source Separation, it is not meant for frequency filtering. If your signal though is made of three independent sources at 3Hz, 8Hz and 13 Hz, then the result will be similar to applying a filter splitting as you mention. But with ICA, you do not get to choose which frequencies you filter. You can only choose the number of sources you want to recover.

Comment: Thanks @demienfrancois for your reply, put a professor told me that you can use fastICA to separate the bands of the signal based on frequency. Are you sure ?

Comment: This is what I recollect, but I haven't been using FastICA for a while